# PIC demo board USART

Tags: pic, c, uart

I am trying to create a gps application but dont get good data. I have heard that the most common fault is to use a invalid baud rate but so I have tried to look at it but without success. The PIC I am using is a pic18f45k20 with the internal oscillator. The problem is that the variable rx in the getPosition function dont get a good value. I also tried to change the ReadUSART to getcUsart but I get the same value with those two functions. i am using MPLAB X with the xc8 compiler. Also the gps module is http://www.servicepunkten.com/downloads/GlobalTop-FGPMMOPA6H-Datasheet-V0B.pdf

My code for init:

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000
void initUsart(){
TRISCbits.RC6 = 0; //TX pin set as output
TRISCbits.RC7 = 1; //RX pin set as input

CloseUSART();
UART1Config = USART_TX_INT_OFF & USART_RX_INT_OFF & USART_ASYNCH_MODE & USART_EIGHT_BIT & USART_BRGH_HIGH ;
baud = 103;
OpenUSART(UART1Config,baud);

//compare with the table above
RCIF = 0; //reset RX pin flag
RCIP = 1; //High priority
RCIE = 1; //Enable RX interrupt
PEIE = 1; //Enable pheripheral interrupt (serial port is a pheripheral)

ei();       //remember the master switch for interrupt?

}

void setupClock()
{
OSCCONbits.IRCF0 = 1;
OSCCONbits.IRCF1 = 1;
OSCCONbits.IRCF2 = 1;
}

#define PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCONLY "$PMTK314,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0*29"
#define PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_10HZ "$PMTK220,100*2F"
#define PMTK_SET_BAUD_9600 "$PMTK251,9600*17"

void initGps(){
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    WriteUSART(PMTK_SET_BAUD_9600[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    WriteUSART(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_10HZ[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < 49; i++){
    WriteUSART(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCONLY[i]);
}
}
```

code for reading:

```
void interrupt interrupts(){

if(PIR1bits.RCIF == 1)
{
    handleUsartRx();
}
if(INTCONbits.TMR0IF == 1)
{
    handleTmr0();
}
}

void handleUsartRx(){
struct Position position = getPosition();
//do stuff with position
PIR1bits.RCIF = 0; // clear rx flag
}
struct Position getPosition(){
struct Position position;
position.fixed = -1;
rx = ReadUSART(); //read the byte from rx register

if(rx == '$'){
    rxIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        receivedData[i] = '\0';
    }
}
receivedData[rxIndex] = rx;
rxIndex++;

//Dont know which is the end string
if(strstr(&receivedData,"<CR><LF>") == NULL && strstr(&receivedData,"<CR> <LF>") == NULL){

    return position;
}

//EndString is found, start parsing;
char *parsedString[9];
splitNmeaString(parsedString);
position = createPosition(parsedString);

return position;
}
```

Comment: What data *do* you get?

Comment: I should get data like: $GPRMC,123519,A,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,022.4,084.4,230394,003.1,W*6A but I get chars like '$', 'F','´', TAB etc etc almost never a number

Comment: Your test for end of line doesn't look right.  Usually strings like "<CR><LF>" are just used for documentation.  You really want to check for "\r\n" (or individually like '\r' and '\n').  "<CR> <LF>" makes no sense, even if it was shown as "\r \n", as I've never seen a space between the CR and LF.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a lot of processing inside your `handleUsartRx()` function before you clear the interrupt flag, and I suspect that your problem is that you're simply missing a lot of the incoming data.

In particular, you call `strstr()` twice, and this is a relatively expensive function in terms of CPU cycles.

Furthermore, your `strstr()` calls will never succeed, since `<CR>`, etc. is not the correct way to denote a control character in a C string. For a carriage return, for example, use either `\r` or `\x0D`. Linefeed would be either `\n` or `\x0A`.

Since you never find the end of the string, your data buffer just keeps growing, which means that the processing on each new character takes longer and longer.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should make some changes to the design so that the interrupt only gets the char. But I doubt that the problem is caused by it as the chars I'm getting should not be possible to get (like ÿ). About the <CR> I think that I misunderstood the documentation, but it will not make any problems until the data I get is valid

Comment: Also when changing the baud rate I get different results. But I think I have set the clock speed correctly to 16MHz which is the maximum speed for the internal oscillator for my pic.